# Mavericks SSH keys and Keychain

Tags: terminal, macos, password, ssh, keychain

Before Mavericks I could use Keychain to store my SSH keyfile passwords

The connection between private key and Keychain was like this:

ssh-add -K /path/of/private/key

However now in Mavericks, the -K option has been removed.

Of course, I can skip the "-K" option and manually copy paste the password every time I start my computer... but I would rather use the keychain method again.

How can I use Keychain for my ssh private file passwords again? Is it down in a different way now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you sure you aren't using `ssh-add` from another source?  On my Mavs, `ssh-add`—which is `/usr/bin/ssh-add`—does have the `-K` flag.  It's in the manpage, shows in the usage message, and is accepted.

Check `which ssh-add` to see if you're pulling in `ssh-add` from elsewhere due to your `PATH`.